# How to create Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to create a Point of Sale application.It has two class one is `POS` and other is `Bill`.

`POS` class creates an instance of `Bill` Class & `Bill` class handles all the logic to calculate the final bill.

There is one requirement that I don't understand

A single instance of the class `POS` should initiate bills.

1. The interface should be `Bill bill = pos.createBill()`.  Many clients could call `pos.createBill()` method simultaneously on the single `POS` instance, even from different threads.
2. Each call to `pos.createBill()` should return a new instance of the `Bill` class.
3. An instance of `Bill` will be used only in the one thread it was created in.

I don't understand which class should implement thread and how should I call it?

Comment: I don't think you need to do you?  If you need, it would be created else where, like in the `main`...

Comment: Where does it say you must write the code that creates new threads?  I don't see that anywhere.  All I see is a requirement that your pos.createBill() class must be thread-safe, and a non-requirement that says your Bill implementation need not be thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

POS should be use singleton prattern

Answer (score 1):

In Your POS class you should have thread declared as,

```
    Bill bill = new Bill();
    synchronized(bill)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread() { public void run() { 

               //  calls to bill.create bill.

        } };
        t.start();
        t.join();
    }
```

also As suggested above POS should be Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Why "Each call to pos.createBill() should return a new instance of the Bill class."???
Just use one Bill object

```
Bill bill = pos.createBill()
```

create this in Global location (In Main or in Form class,out side of any method within class) and use "Bill" in your method call.  If and only your method taking too much of time to execute one task put those method calling in thread. Use asynchronously (Async) calling.